# Insert text after first letter of pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

How could I insert `/foo/` after and only after opening brackets?

```bsh
(bar)
```

should become

```
(/foo/bar)
```

while `(/baz/bar)` should *not* become `(/baz/foo/bar)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this simple case, you could try

```
sed 's,(bar,(/foo/bar,'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this harcode `bar`? Though the question is not that clear if that's what is wanted.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity You are right, but I assumed from the example ("`(/baz/bar)` should not become `(/baz/foo/bar)`") that the actual task was to prepend `/foo/` to the previously-known fixed string `bar`, with the boundary condition that this should only happen if `bar` is the first word after the opening `(`.

Answer (score 0):

A convoluted way, assuming that you want to add `/foo/` to *any* pattern between parenthesis:

```bsh
$ echo '(bar)' | sed 's;(/*\([^(]*\);(/foo/\1;'
(/foo/bar)

$ echo '(/bar/baz)' | sed 's;(/*\([^(]*\);(/foo/\1;'
(/foo/bar/baz)
```

The command says:

*Select what is between parenthesis and capture it, (could begin with a slash `/`), and replace `(` or `(/` with `/foo/` and the captured pattern*.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

`awk '/\(bar/ {sub(/bar/, "/foo/bar"); }1' input`

With `sed`:

`sed -E 's%([(])(bar)%\1/foo/\2%' input`

This uses backreferences \1 for `(` and \2 for `bar`.